# Pairing word array with image array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a javascript game, where a word (1 out of 9 possible words) pops up on screen and disappears after few seconds. After this disappears 9 corresponding images to the 9 possible words that could appear, appear on screen. I want to link the word arrays with my image arrays so that when a word appears you must click the correct corresponding image to the word to go onto the next level.

How can I connect the two arrays?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet where linking the two arrays are involved. I didn't know where to start, but I'm going to try using a dictionary like user1823 recommended bellow. Will let you know how I get on

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of the "gimme teh code" variety.

Comment: Just have 2 arrays and keep the matching objects on the same indexes. if array1[0] == "apple", make sure array2[0] == "apple.jpg"

and in case the image is always the name + ".jpg", you don't even need a second array.

Comment: I don't want the code, I just want to know what direction to go in so I can look it up

Comment: Thanks a mill, Michael! Will give this a go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, arrays all used 0-based indexing to hold their values, so, if your pictures are in the same position in the picture array as their associated images in the image array, you should be able to access them both with the same index.

Example:

```
var wordArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8", "word9"];
var imageArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7", "image8", "image9"];
```

If you set your arrays up like this, then you can use the same index to reference the paired words/pictures:

```
wordArray[0]  is 'word1'
imageArray[0] is 'image1'

wordArray[1]  is 'word2'
imageArray[1] is 'image2'

. . .

wordArray[8]  is 'word9'
imageArray[8] is 'image9'
```

---

Alternately, you could use a single array of objects that contain the word/picture pairs, instead of two seperate arrays.

```
var data = [
    {word: "word1",
     image: "image1"},
    {word: "word2",
     image: "image2"},

    . . .

    {word: "word9",
     image: "image9"}
];
```

If you went this route, then you would reference the paired words/pictures like this, instead:

```
data[0].word  is 'word1'
data[0].image is 'image1'

data[1].word  is 'word2'
data[1].image is 'image2'

. . .

data[8].word  is 'word9'
data[8].image is 'image9'
```

Comment: Thanks a heap talemyn for your help :)

Comment: where would I put the reference in my code? currently I put it under my arrays but this didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store your information:

```
var data = {"banana": "banana.jpg", "apple": "apple.jpg", ..., "pear": "pear.jpg"}
```

Comment: While I am actually a fan of this kind of structure in many cases, based on the context, if he needs to pick a word randomly (or move through them in a specific order), not having the structure of an array may make it more difficult to do that.

Comment: @talemyn yep, I like to keep it short and simple :) However, I'm a fan of yours too, it's better for direct accessing.

Comment: LOL . . . apologies . . ."user3594463" sounded more like a boy name to me.   ;)